# How can I run my calculations on a remote server?

Tags: high-performance-computing

I'm going to use a more powerful server to run my simulations on it using a remote control software (The server is in another building). It's my first time to try that.

What are the things that I should be aware of? Do I have to install the codes that I'm using on that server too? How can I use it, please?

Comment: It depends on which remote control software you are using, which job scheduler you are using (pbs, slurm...), whether your intended modules are already compiled on the machine or not, etc. Kindly update these details

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin the remote software will be probably TeamViewer . How can I check for job schedular and modules ? It's the first time that I hear these two terms. How they should be normally ?

Comment: The best way to get answers to your question is asking server administrators. Teamviewer is for graphical interface access and normally, you access the login terminal using SSH protocol and then submit your job using a script (designed for the job scheduler software) directly at the linux prompt. There are software like [WebMO](https://www.webmo.net/) that can do the submission directly to the server from your local or even internet.

Comment: @Camps The server administrators don't know about computational modelling. I have to figure out how to do everything by myself. Can you please explain to me step by step what should I do in details. I also added to the post that the server is in another building.

Comment: 1/2 @Camilla I think HPC facilities are usually not equipped with GUI. As far as I know, first, you have to access the command line using [SSH](https://www.howtogeek.com/311287/how-to-connect-to-an-ssh-server-from-windows-macos-or-linux/) (almost always). On your personal computer, you can directly run a program. But for a server, your program should be added to the queue using a workload manager (something like [pbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System) or [slurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager)).

Comment: 2/2  If your server doesn't have the module available to load already, you can compile the program you intended to use. Maybe you can discuss it in [this HPC chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117114/hpqc-high-performance-quantum-computing).

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/how-can-i-submit-jobs-to-an-hpc-scheduler

Comment: Can you share basics like what operating system you are using, what rights you have, do you use a scheduler, do you want to use any graphical interface (or maybe what program you want to use)? Is is an HPC or your own workstation?

Comment: I assume that the remote server is not mentioned anywhere in our [Supercomputers around the world](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1515/5) thread, since you seem to have very little information about the server. Are you able to tell us the name of the server or at least the name of the owner or owning institution? This will help us find the crucial details required to answer your question.

Comment: @Greg it's a server I still don't know what to do or how to use it. It's my first time

Comment: @NikeDattani it's just a server not a supercomputer.

Comment: I had already assumed that it wasn't one of the servers in the "supercomputers around the world" thread, and just asked for the name of the server, so that I could look up things like which job scheduler you use.

Comment: @NikeDattani . How can find it's name? Those are the informations that I got about it by runnung `lscpu` command :                                                                                                                    Architecture: x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order: Little Endian
CPU(s): 24
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-23
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 6
Socket(s): 2
NUMA node(s): 2
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
CPU family: 6
Model: 44
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz
Stepping: 2
CPU MHz: 1600.191
BogoMIPS: 5867.26

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost all HPC servers use [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux). Therefore, in almost all cases, familiarity with Linux is crucial, especially the [basic commands](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/linux-commands) (e.g. `ls`, `cd`, `mkdir`, `cp`, `rm`, etc.).

## Connecting to the server

Connecting to a Linux-based HPC server is now always in my experience done through [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (in the 1990s I used [Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) to log into the University of Toronto servers, but I can't recall using anything other than SSH in the mid-2000s or later). To log into an HPC server with SSH, you can run the following command in the default terminal in Linux, MacOS or Windows Subsystem for Linux, or in something like PuTTY in pure Windows (assuming your username is `camilla` and the server's name is `materials.stackexchange.com`, for a hypothetical example):

```
ssh camilla@materials.stackexchange.com
```

As long as there's no problems, you will next be asked for your password, and upon entering it correctly you will be able to access the server. Usually you will be given a temporary password at the beginning and will be highly encouraged (or forced) to change it immediately. The [passwd](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passwd-command-in-linux-with-examples/) command will allow you to do this if you are not already forced to do it upon your first successful login. The ***spelling*** of that command is a bit strange, and it can be hard to remember whether or leave out the letter "a" or the letters "or", so I spelled it correctly for you in the hyperlinked words in this paragraph.

## Transfer of files

It is very likely that you will have input scripts or data files on a computer that you're currently using, and will want those files to be accessible on the HPC server. A very simple way to transfer files to and from an HPC server is using `scp` (in the 1990s I used FTP, which stands for "file transfer protocol" but now exclusively use `scp` which is just a "secure" analog of the previously mentioned and ***very*** basic `cp` command).  The following command is run on your local machine and is for copying files from your local machine to the above hypothetical server (the important part to remember is the ***colon*** symbol `:` which is easy to forget because we far more often use `cp` without it, than we use `scp` with it):

```
scp file.txt camilla@materials.stackexchange.com:
```

From your local machine you can also copy files from the server to your current directory on your local machine, for example with the following command (the main difference from the above command is the ***order***):

```
scp camilla@materials.stackexchange.com:/path/to/file.txt .
```

## Compiling/installing programs

Most HPC servers do not allow you to have full control of the server, so you are limited in how you can install things. For this reason, and because it's wasteful for 100 users to each install their own copy of a 10GB software, servers often come with most major programs pre-installed. These pre-installed programs are often made available with the [lmod](https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) system. The following `lmod` commands are the most commonly used ones, and my example below is for Python but could be used for other programs by changing the last word in the each command accordingly:

```
module load python    # load the system's default version of Python
module unload python  # unload whatever version of Python was loaded
module spider python  # learn information about the various versions of Python modules that are made available to you
```

To see which modules you already have loaded, you can run:

```
module list
```

and to see which ones are available to load via `module load`, you can run:

```
module avail
```

When programs are not available via the `lmod` system, then your next option might be `pip`, but this can be significantly more complicated than using `pip` on your local machine, for example Compute Canada which serves almost every Canadian academic researcher has a "wheel house" for Python wheels, which is described [here](https://docs.alliancecan.ca/wiki/Available_Python_wheels), and `pip install` has to actually be run every time you run a job (so it's part of the "job submission script") as described here: [How can I build the wheels necessary for a quick installation of PySCFad on a "compute node"?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10588/5). Likewise, compiling software the "traditional way" from "source" can be significantly more complicated than on a local machine as you may have to "load" compilers as modules (among other things), and you can see an example of the sequence of commands for this type of installation here: [Is this "internal error" reproducible when compiling OpenMolcas on other Intel compilers?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10211/5)

## Running calculations

Explanations of how to use SLURM, LoadLeveler, and SGE are provided in answers here: [How can I submit jobs to an HPC scheduler?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6497/5). This discussion is also related: [Job scheduler alternatives](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/862/5). The [job-scheduler](/questions/tagged/job-scheduler) tag here on MMSE is for asking questions about schedulers like the ones mentioned in this paragraph.

## Logging out of the server

When you run the command:

```
logout
```

the terminal that you have been using all this time will return you to the directory on your *local* machine at which you were present at the time of logging into the server.

Comment: I found that in the server ubuntu 16.04 is the one installed there and I have ubuntu 20 in my laptop will that cause me problems

Comment: When I tried `load module python` command it's not working, same problem for `load module python3`

Comment: Note that Windows 10 and 11 (the only currently supported/updated versions of Windows) have OpenSSH preinstalled. Installing PuTTY is rarely necessary or useful these days.

Comment: Thank you so much Nike for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: When I do `exit` or `logout` to logout from the server then close my laptop can that stop the calculation in the server? And how can I check the calculation after I come back?

Comment: @Camilla please ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

We need more detail to effectively help you to use your remote server well. However, a good starting point is the HPC Carpentry's "HPC Intro" course: https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/hpc-intro/.

You should run through this course on your own, and also send this course to the administrators of your remote server and ask them if (1) the course is a suitable introduction to using this particular server, and if not, (2) what they would like you to do differently to the course.